# Does flot v0.5 support IE8 RTM?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, flot

[flot v0.5](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) fails to render correctly in IE8 RTM. I am using excanvas library that comes packaged with flot (as per instructions).

The [project description](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) states that IE8 is supported but doesn't mention which mode (compat or standards).

Does anyone have experience using flot v0.5 with IE8?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried loading the [Flot examples](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/) in IE 8. It only worked when I enabled the compatibility view button which suggests it is only known to currently work in compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes. That's the conclusion I arrived at. I've posted a bug report on flot project site. Hopefully the author has time to look into this.

Comment: This has now been fixed and will be available in the next Flot release: http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=140